# compare two successive rows - group by

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

i have a model as below

```
ID     Date                    BoitierNumber
1      07/04/2012 14:01:46     1
2      07/04/2012 14:01:50     2
3      07/04/2012 14:01:50     3
4      07/04/2012 14:01:56     1
5      07/04/2012 14:02:06     1
6      07/04/2012 14:02:10     2
```

I have grouped rows by (BoitierNumber)

```
*boitier Number 1

 1      07/04/2012 14:01:46
 4      07/04/2012 14:01:56 
 5      07/04/2012 14:02:06

*boitier Number 2

 2      07/04/2012 14:01:50
 6      07/04/2012 14:02:10 

*boitier Number 3

 3      07/04/2012 14:01:50
```

To do this i have used this code

```
var groups = context.Essais.GroupBy(p => p.BoitierNumber)
                .Select(g => new { GroupName = g.Key, Members = g });

foreach (var g in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Members of {0}", g.GroupName);

    foreach (var member in g.Members.OrderBy(x=>x.Id))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}     {1}", member.Id,member.Date);
    }
}
```

For the moment everything works fine
now i want to compare the date of two successives grouped rows
if row[i].date>row[i-1].date i will delete row[i-1]

For example:

```
*boitier Number 1

 1      07/04/2012 14:01:46
 4      07/04/2012 14:01:56 
 5      07/04/2012 14:02:06 
 8      07/04/2012 14:01:00 
 10     07/04/2012 14:00:00 
 13     07/04/2012 14:03:00 
 boitier Number 1 
 ---> Date of row of Id 4 > Date of row of ID 1
 then i will delete row of ID 1
 ---> Date of row of Id 5 > Date of row of ID 4
 then i will delete row of ID 4
 ---> Date of row of Id 8 < Date of row of ID 5
 then i will skip it
 ---> Date of row of Id 10 < Date of row of ID 8
 then i will skip it
 ---> Date of row of Id 13 > Date of row of ID 10
 then i will delete row of ID 10
 ...

 TherFore, After this process, only rows 13 and 8 will be remain
```

Comment: When you say delete, do you mean delete from the database?

Comment: yes i want to delete the rows from database.

Comment: Why not use a for instead of a foreach and check the previous item (i-1)?

Comment: @AdrianIftode that's what i want
but when i use a for loop
`for (var i=0; i< g.Members.OrderBy(x=>x.Id).count();i++)`
//i don't know how to access of member[i].id member[i].date...

Comment: @ElloumiAhmed add a `.ToList()` call after ordering the items. `var members = g.Members.OrderBy(x=>x.Id).ToList();` Then you can call `members[i]` and `members[i-1]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest change you can do now is:

```
var groups = context.Essais.GroupBy(p => p.BoitierNumber)
                .Select(g => new 
                                { 
                                  GroupName = g.Key, 
                                  Members = g.OrderBy(m=>m.Id)
                                });
```

**EDIT** 
*It seems EF doesn't work with calling ToList() in the projection.*

The Members will be now an ordered list by id, then you can do a for instead a foreach

```
foreach (var g in groups)
{
    var members = g.Members.ToList();
    for (int i = 1, i < members.Count; i++)
    {
         var previousMember = members[i-1];
         var currentMember = members[i];
         if (..)
             // code to delete
    }
}
```

*Just a note.* Projecting the grouped Members with the initial query, it will create other queries to select the members corresponding to the each group key. You'll still load the entire table, but in subsequent queries. You can do the grouping in memory:

```
var groups = context.Essais
                      .AsEnumberable().
                      .GroupBy(p => p.BoitierNumber)
                      .Select(g => new { GroupName = g.Key, Members = g.OrderBy(m=>m.Id).ToList()  });
```

Comment: In your `for` do you mean to use the variable `groups`? Also, why are you starting the loop at 1 and not zero?

Comment: @SteveMallory, this for would be used inside the first iterator. I'm starting at 1 so there would be a previous. I'll edit my answer, maybe is not clear.

Comment: @AdrianIftode i get this error `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '« System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Model.Essai] ToList[Essai](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[Model.Essai])` in line foreach (var g in groups)

Comment: @ElloumiAhmed, I can't tell why (have you added the using System.Linq?)

Comment: @ElloumiAhmed, try the second way. I believe calling ToList() in the main query causes the error.

Comment: @ElloumiAhmed, I edited it, see my new changes, let me know if it works